# Is it possible to assign this bit of code that's been bothering me to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is kind of a dumb question, but I'm only just starting to study JavaScipt (& programming in general) and I'm struggling with a bit of code.

I'm trying to make this if/else statement where I verify whether the value of a button is different from a determinate set of buttons. Here's the code in question:

```js
const listaDeTeclas = document.querySelectorAll('.tecla');
const teclaSoma = document.querySelector('.operacao_soma');
const teclaSubt = document.querySelector('.operacao_subtrai');
const teclaMult = document.querySelector('.operacao_multiplica');
const teclaDivi = document.querySelector('.operacao_divide');

for (let i = 0; i < listaDeTeclas.length; i++) {
    let tecla = listaDeTeclas[i];
    let valor = tecla.innerHTML;
    
    tecla.onclick = function () {
        if (valor != teclaSoma.innerHTML && valor != teclaSubt.innerHTML && valor != teclaMult.innerHTML && valor != teclaDivi.innerHTML) {
            calcDisplay.innerHTML += valor;
        } else if (valor == teclaSoma.innerHTML || valor == teclaSubt.innerHTML || valor == teclaMult.innerHTML || valor == teclaDivi.innerHTML) {
            console.log('it works!');    
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably looking pretty bad, but the thing that's bothering me the most is the `valor == teclaSoma.innerHTML || valor == teclaSubt.innerHTML || valor == teclaMult.innerHTML || valor == teclaDivi.innerHTML` bit. Would there be a way to store this line in specific in a variable so that the if/else statement can look something the following?

```js
if (valor != theVariableIDontKnowHowToMake) {
  calcDisplay.innerHTML += valor;
} else if (valor == theVariableIDontKnowHowToMake) {
  console.log('it works!');
}
```

The code works for it's purposes as it is, but it just looks ***ugly*** to me...

Comment: slightly better alternative `[teclaSoma.innerHTML, teclaSubt.innerHTML, teclaMult.innerHTML, teclaDivi.innerHTML].includes(valor)` - or if you set all the assignments to `teclaSoma = document.querySelector('.operacao_soma').innerHTML` etc, then you can shorten it to `[teclaSoma, teclaSubt, teclaMult, teclaDivi].includes(valor)`

Comment: though, to be honest, you don't need the `if` in `else if` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing the text, give all your operators the `operacao` class, and/or all your digits the `digito` class. Then you can [check for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) either of them directly:

```
const listaDeTeclas = document.querySelectorAll('.tecla');

for (let tecla of listaDeTeclas) {
    tecla.onclick = () => {
        if (tecla.classList.contains('digito')) {
            calcDisplay.append(tecla.textContent);
        } else {
            console.log('it works!');    
        }
    };
}
```

You may not even want the different types of buttons to share an event handler at that point:

```
const teclaSoma = document.querySelector('.operacao_soma');
const teclaSubt = document.querySelector('.operacao_subtrai');
const teclaMult = document.querySelector('.operacao_multiplica');
const teclaDivi = document.querySelector('.operacao_divide');
const digitos = document.querySelectorAll('.digito');

for (let digito of digitos) {
    digito.onclick = () => {
        calcDisplay.append(digito.textContent);
    };
}

teclaSoma.onclick = () => {
    console.log('TODO: perform +');
};

// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be a way to store this line in specific in a variable...?

Yes, it's as simple as, for example:

```js
const isOperator = valor === teclaSoma.innerHTML || valor === teclaSubt.innerHTML ||
  valor === teclaMult.innerHTML || valor === teclaDivi.innerHTML;

if (isOperator) {
  console.log('it works!');
} else {
  calcDisplay.innerHTML += valor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```js
if ([
  teclaSoma.innerHTML,
  teclaSubt.innerHTML,
  teclaMult.innerHTML,
  teclaDivi.innerHTML
].includes(value)) {
  // stuff
} else {
  // stuff
}
```

Using an array and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) you can simplify the code already a lot.

Also, there is no need to do something akin to `if (x) { } else if (!x) { }` because you can just do `if (x) { } else { }`.

You could make the code even shorter by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping the elements to their HTML:

```js
if ([teclaSoma, teclaSubt, teclaMult, teclaDivi].map(e => e.innerHTML).includes(value)
```

...or, you could combine the `map` and `includes` into a call to [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (which checks whether *some* elements in the array match the condition):

```js
if ([teclaSoma, teclaSubt, teclaMult, teclaDivi].some(e => e.innerHTML === value))
```